# How to reset MySQL root password using xampp/phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

I set the password on the phpmyadmin in xampp, but now it gives this error.

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

These are my PHP configuration.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

when I try to change the password through xampp shell it give this error.

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

how can I solve this?

The version of xampp: 3.2.2

Comment: Did you try to connect to the `mysql` through `shell`?

Comment: Yes but gives error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`